# Multiple criteria for including / excluding rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, aggregate

**CLARIFICATION UPDATE**

Unfortunately we report based on the 3rd party application and database so we cannot modify the datatypes since we do not own it.

To help clarify, This report basically shows us all `ORDERS` that do not have a status of '80' and '90' which are 'completed' order in our system.

The operations manager would like for the report to show us all orders that also DO have a status of 80 or 90 but only if it has recent changed to that order status within 7 mins. If you noticed on the query I have attempted to create a query in the select line that will show times elapse since the status has changed (I am doing this by comparing the `CONSOL_END_TIME` column vs `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)

I essentially would like the report to pick up ALL `ORDER_NO` between `20-70` and only the '80' and '90' if the `consol_end_time` was only 7 mins prior to the `current_timestamp`.

Hope that helps, if you need more clarification, please advise.
I have updated the query to better show what I am trying to accomplish..

```
SELECT * 
     , SUBSTRING(PM.SHIP_TIME, 1, 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(PM.SHIP_TIME, 3, 2)+':'+RIGHT(PM.SHIP_TIME, 2) AS MANIFEST_TIME
     , CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,114) AS CURR_TIME
     , DATEDIFF(MINUTE,SUBSTRING(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 1, 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 3, 2)+':'+RIGHT(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 2),CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,114)) AS MINS_ELAPSED  
FROM PK_HEADER H 
            JOIN PK_SHIPPING S ON H.ORDER_NUM = S.ORDER_NUM 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN CARRIER_CFG C ON S.SERVICE_CODE = C.SERVICE_CODE 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN ROUTING_PACK R ON H.ROOT_CNTNR = R.CNTNR_ID 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN PK_MANIFEST PM ON (H.ORDER_NUM = PM.ORDER_NUM) -- JUST JOIN TO THE MANIFEST TABLE TO GET THE TIME IT WAS MANIFESTED
WHERE CUST_NUM = @CUSTOMER 
        AND @SERVICE = S.SERVICE_CODE
        AND @ADD1 = S.SHIP_ADDRESS_1
        AND @ZIP = S.SHIP_POSTAL_CODE
        AND (H.ORDER_STATUS BETWEEN 20 AND 70 
             OR (H.ORDER_STATUS IN ('80','90'))) 
        OR SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,SUBSTRING(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 1, 2) +':'+SUBSTRING(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 3, 2)+':'+RIGHT(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 2),CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,114)) < '7')
        AND H.LARGE_ORDER = 'Y' 
        AND CREATION_DATE > 20120701 


ORDER BY 
     H.LARGE_ORDER DESC
    ,H.ORDER_STATUS ASC
    ,H.ASSOC_DATE ASC
    ,H.ASSOC_TIME ASC
```

**THE ORIGINAL QUERY BEFORE ANY MODIFICATIONS AT ALL**

```
declare @customer char(18) 
declare @service char(18)
declare @add1 char(40)
declare @zip char(18)


select top 1 @customer = cust_num, @service = s.service_code , @add1 = S.SHIP_ADDRESS_1, @zip = S.SHIP_POSTAL_CODE
FROM PK_HEADER H JOIN PK_LINE L on H.order_num = L.order_num JOIN PK_SHIPPING S ON H.ORDER_NUM = S.ORDER_NUM LEFT OUTER JOIN CARRIER_CFG C ON S.SERVICE_CODE = C.SERVICE_CODE LEFT OUTER JOIN ROUTING_PACK R ON H.ROOT_CNTNR = R.CNTNR_ID 
where L.PKG_ID = '{?Package}'

select * FROM PK_HEADER H /* JOIN PK_LINE L on H.order_num = L.order_num */ JOIN PK_SHIPPING S ON H.ORDER_NUM = S.ORDER_NUM LEFT OUTER JOIN CARRIER_CFG C ON S.SERVICE_CODE = C.SERVICE_CODE LEFT OUTER JOIN ROUTING_PACK R ON H.ROOT_CNTNR = R.CNTNR_ID 
where cust_num  = @customer and @service = s.service_code and @add1 = S.SHIP_ADDRESS_1 and @zip = S.SHIP_POSTAL_CODE and H.ORDER_STATUS BETWEEN 20 AND 70 and h.large_order = 'Y' and creation_date > 20120701


ORDER BY H.LARGE_ORDER DESC, H.ORDER_STATUS asc, H.ASSOC_DATE ASC, H.ASSOC_TIME ASC



INSERT INTO DATA
INSERT INTO [dbo].[PK_HEADER]
           ([ORDER_NUM]
           ,[COMPANY_CODE]
           ,[CUST_NUM]
           ,[CREATION_DATE]
           ,[CREATION_TIME]
           ,[DUE_DATE]
           ,[DUE_TIME]
           ,[ORDER_PRIORITY]
           ,[ORDER_STATUS]
           ,[ASSIGNMENT_ZONE_NUM]
           ,[ON_HOLD]
           ,[ORDER_CANCEL]
           ,[ROOT_CNTNR]
           ,[PICK_CONSOL]
           ,[HAD_BKORDER]
           ,[MISS_INV]
           ,[SUPERVISOR_AUTH]
           ,[INCOMPLETE_INS]
           ,[CONSOL_ROUTING]
           ,[CONSOL_ST_DATE]
           ,[CONSOL_ST_TIME]
           ,[CONSOL_END_DATE]
           ,[CONSOL_END_TIME]
           ,[SPECIAL_HANDL]
           ,[ELAPSED_PACK_TIME]
           ,[SHIP_CNTNR_PREV]
           ,[SHIP_CNTNR_TOTAL]
           ,[MANF_CNTNR_TOTAL]
           ,[ORDER_EXPORT]
           ,[ORDER_TYPE]
           ,[WAVE_TYPE]
           ,[WAVE_ID]
           ,[ORIG_ORDER_PRIORITY]
           ,[ORDER_VALUE]
           ,[ORDER_WEIGHT]
           ,[LARGE_ORDER]
           ,[PROD_SUBSTN_OVERRIDE]
           ,[ASSOC_DATE]
           ,[ASSOC_TIME]
           ,[TRAILER_SEQ]
           ,[HOST_ORDER_NUM]
           ,[HOST_ORDER_NUM_2]
           ,[HOST_OP]
           ,[TRAILER_ROUTE]
           ,[DESTINATION]
           ,[HOLD_REASON]
           ,[CANCEL_REASON])
     VALUES
           (<ORDER_NUM, char(25),>
           ,<COMPANY_CODE, char(15),>
           ,<CUST_NUM, char(15),>
           ,<CREATION_DATE, char(8),>
           ,<CREATION_TIME, char(6),>
           ,<DUE_DATE, char(8),>
           ,<DUE_TIME, char(6),>
           ,<ORDER_PRIORITY, numeric(18,0),>
           ,<ORDER_STATUS, smallint,>
           ,<ASSIGNMENT_ZONE_NUM, char(3),>
           ,<ON_HOLD, char(1),>
           ,<ORDER_CANCEL, char(1),>
           ,<ROOT_CNTNR, char(25),>
           ,<PICK_CONSOL, char(1),>
           ,<HAD_BKORDER, char(1),>
           ,<MISS_INV, char(1),>
           ,<SUPERVISOR_AUTH, char(1),>
           ,<INCOMPLETE_INS, int,>
           ,<CONSOL_ROUTING, char(1),>
           ,<CONSOL_ST_DATE, char(8),>
           ,<CONSOL_ST_TIME, char(6),>
           ,<CONSOL_END_DATE, char(8),>
           ,<CONSOL_END_TIME, char(6),>
           ,<SPECIAL_HANDL, char(3),>
           ,<ELAPSED_PACK_TIME, numeric(18,0),>
           ,<SHIP_CNTNR_PREV, int,>
           ,<SHIP_CNTNR_TOTAL, int,>
           ,<MANF_CNTNR_TOTAL, int,>
           ,<ORDER_EXPORT, char(1),>
           ,<ORDER_TYPE, smallint,>
           ,<WAVE_TYPE, smallint,>
           ,<WAVE_ID, char(20),>
           ,<ORIG_ORDER_PRIORITY, numeric(18,0),>
           ,<ORDER_VALUE, real,>
           ,<ORDER_WEIGHT, real,>
           ,<LARGE_ORDER, char(1),>
           ,<PROD_SUBSTN_OVERRIDE, smallint,>
           ,<ASSOC_DATE, char(8),>
           ,<ASSOC_TIME, char(6),>
           ,<TRAILER_SEQ, int,>
           ,<HOST_ORDER_NUM, char(30),>
           ,<HOST_ORDER_NUM_2, char(30),>
           ,<HOST_OP, char(10),>
           ,<TRAILER_ROUTE, char(30),>
           ,<DESTINATION, char(20),>
           ,<HOLD_REASON, char(3),>
           ,<CANCEL_REASON, char(3),>)
GO
```

Comment: Can you show a few rows of sample data and desired results? You're mixing a lot of things here that I don't know will work well together (if at all), most importantly SUM / HAVING without any grouping.

Comment: (And also, if you know the data types are wrong, why not fix them?)

Comment: Aaron, sorry for the late reply. Thanks for helping me look into this.... unfortunately we report based on the 3rd party application and database so we cannot modify the datatypes since we do not own it.

To help clarify, This report basically shows us all ORDERS that do not have a status of '80' and '90' which are 'completed' order in our system.

The operations manager would like for the report to show us all orders that also DO have a status of 80 or 90 but only if it has recent changed to that order status. I am going to re-edit the original question since I am running out of characters

Comment: And you tell if something is "completed" by performing some kind of aggregate operation against part of the end_time value? Also this: `AND CREATION_DATE > 20120701` is wrong, it should be: `AND CREATION_DATE > '20120701'`.

Comment: The system actually uses the order status of '80' or '90' to determine if its completed. the CONSOL_END_TIME is a column I found to compare the current time_stamp and track whether or not the order_status changed within the last 7 minutes.

Comment: You still haven't shown us what any single value of `CONSOL_END_TIME` might actually look like.

Comment: 'CONSOL_END_TIME' returns values like '115708' or '124823' or '195816' or 'NULL' they are in 24HR format not 12HR

Comment: Do you mean `NULL` or `'NULL'`? There is a difference. And what is the data type? CHAR(6)? VARCHAR(8)? NVARCHAR(MAX)?

Comment: datatype : 'CONSOL_END_TIME, char(6)'  IN SSMS I get results with the query written as `SELECT * FROM PK_HEADER H  where h.consol_end_time = 'NULL'`

WHEN I TRY `SELECT * FROM PK_HEADER H  where h.consol_end_time = NULL'` I get no results

Comment: Im going to try `AND H.CONSOL_END_TIME >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -7, CONVERT(CHAR, GETDATE(), 108))` in the meantime just to atleast try other options

Comment: That's not going to work - as soon as it hits `'NULL'` or an invalid time, you'll see `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.` Also, [don't specify types like `char` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: Ok perfect implementing your changes now. There is a field that would represent the date called `CONSOL_END_DATE, char(8)` which stores data like '20150707' and 'NULL'

Comment: Next time please provide all of that information up front. I asked for it 5 days ago and have spent 5 days teasing little bits of info from you.

Comment: Will do Aaron, I am implementing the latest revision now. Thank you again for taking the time to help me out with this, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't know why you think you need a `SUM` here, or why you're doing all that manipulation to the `CONSOL_END_TIME` column. Your word problems lead me to change this:

```
    AND (H.ORDER_STATUS BETWEEN 20 AND 70 
         OR (H.ORDER_STATUS IN ('80','90'))) 
         OR SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,SUBSTRING(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 1, 2) +':'
    +SUBSTRING(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 3, 2)+':'
    +RIGHT(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 2),CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,114)) < '7')
```

To this:

```
AND
(
  (
    H.ORDER_STATUS NOT IN (80,90)
  )
  OR
  (
    H.ORDER_STATUS IN (80,90)
    AND 
    -- this is the nonsense you get yourself into when you use the wrong data types
    CASE WHEN ISDATE(CONSOL_END_DATE + ' ' +
     STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONSOL_END_TIME),5,0,':'),3,0,':')) = 1
    THEN CONSOL_END_DATE + ' ' +
     STUFF(STUFF(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),CONSOL_END_TIME),5,0,':'),3,0,':') END
       >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)

  )
)
```

(Removed the convert to `time` since you've now revealed that you're not using 2008 R2 after all.)

Still a heck of a lot more readable than all those `SUBSTRING`/`RIGHT` calls. Note that this will allow invalid times (like `'999999'`) and it still doesn't reflect anything about the *day* the event happened on. Is there another column perhaps that represents the date?

But I can only be sure that's right if you provide table structure (data types are important), and enough sample data to cover all of these scenarios:

1. Is completed (status not in 80,90) - *should be included in result*
2. Is not completed but changed in the last seven minutes - *should be included*
3. Is not completed and changed more than seven minutes ago - *should
   not be included*
4. Is not completed and changed > 24 hours and 7 minutes ago but < 24 hours ago (e.g. if it is 14:32 right now, then something from 14:35 yesterday); currently I think you are ignoring the *date* of the status change - *should not be included*

I could invent that data but I'm more after the data types to be sure there are no explicit conversions or other changes required, and the actual data that is in `CONSOL_END_TIME` (it is not clear from just your query).

Comment: I see, I just verified the datatype for consol_end_time is (char(8),null)

Your above statements (1,2,3) are correct.

When I added your suggestion, it gave me a Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ORDER'.'

Comment: @Hector It's CHAR(8)? Great. Now can you provide some sample data? I'm not asking for that repeatedly to be a pain, I'm asking for it so I can help you get to a working solution.

Comment: No worries at all. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out with this, I have been driving myself up the wall with this all because of bad datatypes. When you say sample data, would you like to see a screenshot of how the data looks in ssms?

Comment: I am currently testing out your solution but converted here is my example
`(
  (
    H.ORDER_STATUS NOT IN (80,90)
  )
  OR
  (
    H.ORDER_STATUS IN (80,90)
    AND SUBSTRING(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 1, 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 3, 2)+':'+RIGHT(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 2) > DATEADD(MINUTE, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  )
)` I will keep you posted. Thanks!

Comment: Quick update since I just saw your modification,

I just tied the (
  (
    H.ORDER_STATUS NOT IN (80,90)
  )
  OR
  (
    H.ORDER_STATUS IN (80,90)
    AND >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -7, CONVERT(TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
  )
) and its throwing a incorrect syntax near '<' I think its due to the convert(time, current_timestamp) because of the datatype

Comment: @Hector No, it's just sloppy code, try again, and please stop using all this SUBSTRING junk against that column. If you can provide CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements to give the structure and representative data, I could actually test my queries against that, instead of just eyeballing a rewrite. I don't want a screenshot of the data in SSMS, but that would be better than nothing.

Comment: Aaron, I wont be able to confirm until tomorrow but I believe you have steered me in the right direction. It appears that `( ( H.ORDER_STATUS NOT IN (80,90) ) OR ( H.ORDER_STATUS IN (80,90) AND SUBSTRING(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 1, 2)+':'+SUBSTRING(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 3, 2)+':'+RIGHT(H.CONSOL_END_TIME, 2) > DATEADD(MINUTE, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) ) )` is going to end up working. I am going to have a few members test out the report tomorrow in PROD (tomorrow afternoon). I will be sure to keep you posted. Thank you again (I cant say it enough) on taking the time to take multiple stabs at this!

Comment: Aaron, please check the edit to the  original question for the updated insert statement layout

Comment: Aaron, I went ahead and implemented `AND H.CONSOL_END_TIME >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -7, CONVERT(TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))`

I received the following error: Type TIME is not a defined system type.
So I went ahead and removed the CONVERT and just left it as AND H.CONSOL_END_TIME >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -7, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)  and its running now, I will re-implement and have them test it again in the morning in PROD.

Comment: @Hector That error should only occur on SQL Server 2005 or earlier. Your question is tagged with SQL Server 2008 R2. Are you sure you're using SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: I am positive I am using SQLSERVER 2008 R2. I thought the same thing. I wonder if its due to us not needing to convert the datetime datatype that current_timestamp returns for this particular query. We should have an update by this afternoon to see if the latest version of your suggestion works. I will keep you posted and thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Hector Where are you verifying that you are using SQL Server 2008 R2? `SELECT @@VERSION;` or Help > About?

Comment: I will have to admit that I have been corrected and apologize for giving you incorrect information, I just did SELECT @@VERSION and its showing 2005 which I am assuming is the DATABASE version. We have SQL2008 r2 installed for a completely separate database and SSMS is 2008 and 2012 but the DB version for this particular application/DB is being returned as SQL 2005. I am updating this question with that information now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: This worked Aaron. Thank you again for your thorough assistance, I seriously cant thank you enough.